# есть цифровая клавиатура. нужно при каждом клике на кнопки менять рандомно числа на них, кроме 2 пустых

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".btn").each(function() {
    $(this).html(Math.floor(Math.random() * (10) + 0));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="btn_number">
  <li><button class="btn btn01" value="1">1</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn02" value="2">2</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn03" value="3">3</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn04" value="4">4</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn05" value="5">5</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn06" value="6">6</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn07" value="7">7</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn08" value="8">8</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn09" value="9">9</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn empty" value=""></button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn00" value="0">0</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn empty" value=""></button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `if($(this).val() != '')`

Comment: сейчас числа меняются на кнопках, но с повторениями. и на 2 пустых кнопках соответственно появляются числа. подскажите как это исправить, я так понимаю нужно написать условие.

Comment: спасибо) все работает. как теперь сделать так, чтобы числа на кнопках не повторялись?

Comment: У вас уже есть все цифры от 0 до 9. Вы можете пробежаться по кнопкам в цикле и менять их местами рандомно с другими. 1 поменять на 7, 2 на 3,  3 на 6 и тд...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  shuffle();
});

function shuffle(){
  // Берём все кнопки без класса empty
  let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn:not(.empty)'));
  
  while(btns.length > 0){ // Пока кнопки есть
    // Берём первую в массиве и рандомную (обе из массива убираются)
    let a = btns.shift(), n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (btns.length - 1)), b = btns[n];
    btns.splice(n, 1);


    // Просто меняем значения местами
    let [av, bv] = [a.textContent, b.textContent];
    a.textContent = bv;
    b.textContent = av;
  }
}
```

```css
li{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ece8e8;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
  background: #dadada;
}
.btn:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.btn_number{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="btn_number">
  <li><button class="btn btn01" value="1">1</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn02" value="2">2</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn03" value="3">3</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn04" value="4">4</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn05" value="5">5</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn06" value="6">6</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn07" value="7">7</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn08" value="8">8</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn09" value="9">9</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn empty" value=""></button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn00" value="0">0</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn empty" value=""></button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: все работает) спасибо) и за комменты в коде, тк только изучаю js и это облегчает понимание происходящего.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Спасибо тут выражается через плюс и, если помогло, принятие ответа (галочка слева от ответа).